# Is there a Gem that checks that all DB records are valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

When adding validations, it's easy to make the data already in the DB invalid.

Is there a Gem that validates the data in the DB?

It should be easy to just load all records and see if they're valid, but if something already exists I don't want to reinvent it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a gem that does this as it's not a common case that you would have invalid records. I can understand that you may want to do this if you imported a lot of data without validation or created validations after the records are created.

I would do this as a rake task. Depending on the size of your db this can be expensive.

```
namespace :validate do
  desc "validates all records"
  task :check_all_records do
    # get all records
    Module.constants.select { |c| (eval c).is_a? Class }.each do |class|
      # load 1000 into memory at a time and check if they're valid
      class.find_each{ |record| fix_the_record_method unless record.valid? }
    end
  end
end
```